# How to get all images and their thumbnails from wp media library

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

I have a function that returns all the images in WordPress media library, but the problem is that it doesn't return all the image sizes of the image, ex: (thumbnail, small, large), it only returns the original image.

```
function get_images_highcompress_data()
{

     $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png',
      'post_status' => 'inherit',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'id',
      'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
  $images = array();
  foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
      $images[]= $image->guid;
  }
```

Is there any other function that can get all images URL from the wp media library with all its sizes.

Eg. `Image01.jpg` , `image01-500X500.jpg`, `Image01-1080X1080.jpg`, `Image02.jpg` , `image02-500X500.jpg`, `Image02-1080X1080.jpg` Like this in one single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

1. Get a list of all available thumbnail sizes
2. Query all the attachments
3. For each attachment size, get it's URL and save it into the array

Let's change your code into this:

```
function get_images_highcompress_data() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    // Get all the available thumbnail sizes
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    // Query the attachments
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    // Run a loop
    if ( $query_images->have_posts() ){
        while ($query_images->have_posts()){
            $query_images->the_post();
            // For each attachment size, store its URL in an array
            foreach ( $sizes as $key => $size ) {
                $thumbnails[$key] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID(), $size)[0];
            }
            $images = array_merge( $thumbnails , $images );
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

The returned array will look like this:

```
[0] => thumbnail-url,
[1] => medium-url,
[2] => large-url,
```

And so on.

Comment: The output is not it one array it is a kind of nested array! i wan like this 

    [0] => thumbnail-url,
    [1] => medium-url,
    [2] => large-url,
    [3] => thumbnail-url,
    [4] => medium-url,
    [5] => large-url,

Comment: hi there is one issue when i set 'posts_per_page' => 1 it should show only 1 image but it is showing 5 images
 [0] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/20476163_1084404028258493_1412858511354365528_n-150x150.jpg
    [1] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/20476163_1412858511354365528_n-300x284.jpg
    [2] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/204761631412858511354365528_n.jpg
    [3] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/20476163_1084404028258493_1412858511354365528_n.jpg
 ...

Comment: Hi. That's the expected behavior. When you set it to one post per page, it will get only 1 attachment, as expected. _But_, you probably have 5 thumbnail sizes, so it will return 5 images for that single attachment.

Comment: is there any way to do that i want to do ?

Comment: How to get one single long array of all images ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. This code returns a single array of all images. If you want to trim your array, use `array_slice($array, $start, $offset);`. For example, using `array_slice($array, 0, 1);` will only return 1 element of the array.

Comment: The thing is that i want all images in one array like we get when we using single image size so that i can control image count directly from  'posts_per_page' =>

Comment: But it's not possible to do that. Once you set the post per page, you only set the number of attachments, not the thumbnails. You need an extra method such as `array_slice()` to limit that. But it would be nice to add an example to your question by using the edit link.