# How to slice an array using posts_per_page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, codex

The below code shows all the images of wp gallery with all its sizes but it not like that what i want.

```
function get_images_high_data() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    // Get all the available thumbnail sizes
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    // Query the attachments
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );

    $images = array();

    // Run a loop
    if ( $query_images->have_posts() ){

        while ($query_images->have_posts()){

            $query_images->the_post();

            // For each attachment size, store its URL in an array
            foreach ( $sizes as $key => $size ) {

                $thumbnails[$key] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID(), $size)[0];
            }

            $images = array_merge( $thumbnails , $images );
        }

        return $images;
    }
}
```

The returned array will look like this:

```
[0] => thumbnail-url,
[1] => medium-url,
[2] => large-url,
[3] => thumbnail-url,
[4] => medium-url,
[5] => large-url,
```

But when I set `'posts_per_page' => 1` it shows like this

```
    [0] => thumbnail-url,
    [1] => medium-url,
    [2] => large-url,
```

But I want output like below.

```
 [0] => thumbnail-url,
```

If I set `'posts_per_page' => 2` it shows like this

```
 [1] => medium-url,
 [2] => large-url,
```

Comment: So you only want the thumbnail for each attachment image?

Comment: no i want all images but 1 by 1.

Comment: You can simply iterate the array (keys 0 - 5) in your first example.  Use a `foreach` statement and deal with each individually.

Comment: but it will not work according to my need i want that is I set 'posts_per_page' => 1, then if should show 1 image and if I set it to  'posts_per_page' => 2 then it should show 2 images

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in your [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/275422/94498), setting the post per page will not help you. However, there is a workaround.

Instead of directly setting the post per page, use a variable and change that. Then use the same variable to slice the array. For example:

```
$per_page = 2;
// Use the $per_page value to set the posts per page
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
);
// The rest of your code here

    // Now, before returning the images, slice the array using
    // the variable we set before
    $images = array_slice($images, 0, $per_page);
    return $images;
```

Comment: Hi, I need one help the above code is damn slow on big sites which are having 50000+ images can you help me in to optimize and run it faster.

Comment: If you needed help, you could ask a new question instead of unaccepting this once.